# ¿Cómo recargar formulario en javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy empezando con esto del desarrollo web y me encuentro con el siguiente problema.

Tengo un formulario para introducir datos en una pequeña base de datos. Al pulsar en el botón "GUARDAR REGISTRO" el registro de añade a la base de datos o no y me muestra un mensaje de alerta realizado en javascript.  Mi problema es que no sé redirección a la página "index.php" al pulsar el botón de la alerta alerta.

Dejo mi código a ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

```
if(mysqli_query($miconexion, $query)) {
        echo "<script language='javascript'>";
        echo "alert('Registro AÑADIDO CORRECTAMENTE.')";
        echo "windows.location.href = 'index.php'";
        echo "</script>";        
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script language='javascript'>";
        echo "alert('Error!! Vuelve revisa los campos. Los datos no son correctos.')";
        echo "windows.location.href = 'index.php'";
        echo "</script>"; 
    
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Te invito a hacer el [tour]. Por otro lado ¡eso parece PHP! Creo que te falta contar la historia completa y/o añadir etiquetas. Para más información lee [ask]. Un saludo.

Comment: incluya la parte de su html y describa mejor su dificultad para programar esta parte

Comment: Si la pagina a la que estas intentando redireccionar es la misma pagina y esta no posee cambios en su URL creo que si no estoy mal no te va a hacer ninguna redirección, lo otro es que ten en cuenta que tienes un `typo` o error tipografico al momento de llamar a `window` pues tu estas intentando hacer `windows.location.href` cuando enrealidad deberia ser `window.location.href`, de todas maneras NO es necesario hacer redirecciones manuales, si tu tienes un formulario tendras el atributo action que hace la redireccion por ti.

Comment: Un ejemplo es `<form action = "index.php"></form>`, tambien el objeto `windows`, NO existe, usa `window`, ademas, otra cosa importante a tener en cuenta es que todo aquel objeto, propiedad, metodo que haga parte de `window` puede ser referenciado de manera directa sin necesidad de primero llamar a `window` ya que `window` esta en un contexto superglobal, por lo tanto `window.location.href` tambien puede ser reemplazado o acortado a `location.href` y funcionara igualmente.

Comment: Por otro lado, no te aconsejo en lo absoluto que uses `location.href` si lo que quieres es enviar información a otra pagina, usar `location.href` solo es viable para peticiones tipo `GET`, pero si lo haces con `location.href` entonces no es necesario usar un formulario, sin embargo si vas a usar una peticion tipo `POST`, `location.href` no te va a servir, pues no hace tal tipo de petición, el solamente redirige.

Comment: Y de hecho me acabo de dar cuenta que la redireccion la estas intentando hacer en `PHP`, cosa que es curioso si estas usando un formulario, NO uses redirecciones en `PHP` si tienes un formulario, recuerda que el formulario las hace por ti, sin embargo si aun asi quieres redirigir el usuario a otro lado con PHP usa en PHP `header("Location: index.php");`, asumiendo que `index.php` se encuentra al mismo nivel en el codigo.